¿Cómo fijar el footer?
Quisiera que alguien por favor me ayude a solucionar este problema que tengo con el footer; de situarlo siempre al final de la página sin que sobreponga el contenido del main; he intentado con margin-bottom o padding-bottom pero ninguno me puede funcionar:
Aún soy nuevo en lo que es HTML y CSS, quisiera que me ayudaran con ese error por favor



body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100vh;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 1fr 15%;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "main"
    "footer";
}

/*Estructura General*/
header{
    grid-area: header;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 40% 60%;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "encabezado1"
    "encabezado2";

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%; /* Ajuste según grid-template-rows */
    z-index: 1; /* Asegura que el header esté sobre el contenido */
}

main{
    grid-area: main;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "section aside";

    
}

footer{
    grid-area: footer;

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%; /* Ajuste según grid-template-rows */
    z-index: 0; /* Asegura que el footer esté sobre el contenido */
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

/*Estructura Header*/
#encabezado1{
    grid-area: encabezado1;

    text-align: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;

    background-color: blueviolet;
}

#encabezado1 img{
    width: 3%;
    padding: 5px;
}

#encabezado2{
    grid-area: encabezado2;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "info nav";
    
    background-color: brown;
}

#info_perfil{
    grid-area: info;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#info_perfil img{
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu_nav{
    grid-area: nav;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#menucito{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#menucito a{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*Estructura Main*/
section{
    grid-area: section;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

aside{
    grid-area: aside;
    background-color: chocolate;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>INDEX</title>
    <link href="pagPrincipal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="encabezado1">
            <a href="#">Blog</a>        &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Recursos</a>    &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.freepik.com/256/3466/3466092.png?semt=sph" alt="icon1" class="icon">     &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.freepik.com/256/2912/2912761.png?semt=sph" alt="icon2" class="icon">     &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="encabezado2">
            <div id="info_perfil">
                <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.freepik.com/256/1144/1144760.png?semt=ais_hybrid" alt="ft_user">
                <div id="datitos">
                    <h1>Apellidos y Nombre</h1>
                    <p>Mi Web Personal</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav id="menu_nav">
                <ul id="menucito">
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mi Club</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <h2>Artículos de Interés</h2>
            <div id="articulo1">
                <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.freepik.com/256/1828/1828970.png?semt=ais_hybrid" alt="art1">
                <div>
                    <h3>Artículo 1: XYZ</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt praesentium laudantium ab necessitatibus inventore, labore nesciunt perspiciatis omnis voluptatibus maiores vitae hic cupiditate, quod libero fugiat voluptatum vero sapiente nulla.
                        Natus, molestias obcaecati perspiciatis rem enim recusandae dolorum, harum hic nisi inventore illum dolores officiis voluptatum nemo laborum aliquam dolorem, in eum! Ab cum illo vel maiores omnis similique deleniti?
                        Voluptas dignissimos culpa perspiciatis eum, consectetur beatae asperiores dolorum laudantium aut animi possimus at ipsam sed recusandae. Corporis nemo soluta distinctio ab quis obcaecati doloremque quidem natus! Amet, vitae voluptas.
                        Amet aperiam, quos, et placeat sunt eligendi unde doloribus veritatis sapiente saepe consectetur quod! Officiis deleniti, rerum suscipit excepturi optio vitae laborum consequatur! Illum facere laboriosam ducimus laborum, corrupti necessitatibus.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="articulo2">
                <div>
                    <h3>Artículo 2: XYZ</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum necessitatibus itaque incidunt consequuntur tenetur dolor provident, saepe sed quos maiores adipisci aliquid unde assumenda ipsam, asperiores pariatur voluptate facilis maxime!
                        Magnam laborum modi officia minus libero possimus. Voluptate harum sapiente earum quos sint, laborum, labore magni ab minus inventore accusantium iusto id porro qui explicabo magnam! Dolorum nisi amet velit?
                        Vero officia sunt placeat? Asperiores exercitationem iste eaque earum rem, veniam, pariatur explicabo deleniti nisi tempore adipisci. Fuga voluptatibus recusandae quisquam quis iusto hic, obcaecati est quidem aut. Commodi, possimus?
                        Veniam id officiis, beatae laborum maxime iure odio aspernatur nobis at, ratione similique aliquid praesentium. Consequatur odit obcaecati dolores enim ut veniam id possimus, optio iure assumenda quod suscipit numquam!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.freepik.com/256/1828/1828970.png?semt=ais_hybrid" alt="art2">
            </div>
        </section>
        <aside>

        </aside>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>



Quisiera que alguien por favor me ayude a solucionar este problema que tengo con el footer; de situarlo siempre al final de la página sin que sobreponga el contenido del main; he intentado con margin-bottom o padding-bottom pero ninguno me puede funcionar:

Pero un menú fijado se comporta así, esta fijo por sobre todo. Si no lo quieres fijo entonces debes esperar a llegar al final de la página para verlo. Qué otro comportamiento quieres??
